# How to write CSS only for devices which are below than 300px in screen width, but not for all?

Tags: css, mobile-safari, mobile-website

How to write CSS only for devices which are below than 320px in screen width, but not for all?

I want to write CSS like

**Only example to explain to question**

```
devices with min-width of 300 px  { color:red}
devices with max-width of 299 px  { color:blue}
```

And how to control Landscape mode in both condition?

Answer (score 2):

```
myselector { color: blue; }
@media screen and (min-width: 300px) {
  myselector {
    color: red;  
  }
}
```

Though you may need to adjust this as needed depending on whether you care about CSS px width of the viewport or CSS px width of the device screen or something else.  That wasn't clear from the question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a wonderful article that can explain it much better than I can here:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/

Answer (score 1):

I find that this code isn't very reliable on feature phones and some blackberrys. In which case I use [Device Atlas](http://deviceatlas.com/) to get the width on the server side.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 299px) {
  color:blue;
}


@media only screen and (min-device-width: 300px) {
  color:red;
}
```

Comment: but i think in older browser media screen will not work they supports handheld

Comment: it's true, you can get the screen size in the server side code and then set the width using inline CSS. Also using one mark up for all devices is very painful especially for older devices, you may want to limit what devices you support or do some useragent sniffing and serve a different markup for those devices.

Answer (score 1):

It's not as famous as screen and (max-width: or min-width) but CSS3 media queries also allow you to apply css depending on your orientation device.

A code example

@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {

```
/* Portrait styles */
```

}

@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {

```
/* Landscape styles */
```

}

See there specification :
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#orientation

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using javascript.

```
if (document.clientWidth < 300) {
 document.getElementById("yourElement").style.color="blue");
} else if (document.clientWidth >= 300) {
 document.getElementById("yourElement").style.color="red");
}
```

Or something like that.

You could probably also find a way to include a different style sheet if it's under a certain pixel width. I'm not exactly sure how to modify a `<head>` with JS, though, so you'll have to wait for another answer or google around a bit.